# Rotating a straight line by keeping its one end fixed in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to rotate a staright line (eg. second hand in the code) to specific angle keeping it one end fixed, I am able to rotate it but its position is getting changed. How to do that in ActionScript 3?

```
    public function AnalogClockFace(face:Number)
    {
        this.size = face;
    }

    public  function draw():void
    {
        currentTime = new Date();
        showTime(currentTime);
    }

    public function init():void
    {
        this.graphics.clear();
        this.graphics.lineStyle(3.0,0x000000,3.0);
        this.graphics.beginFill(0xABC123,1.0);
        this.graphics.drawCircle(100,500,size);
        this.graphics.endFill();

        secondHand=new Shape();
        secondHand.graphics.lineStyle(2.0,0x000000,1.0);
        secondHand.graphics.moveTo(100,((500-size)+5));
        secondHand.graphics.lineTo(100,500);
        this.addChild(secondHand);
    }
    public function showTime(time:Date):void
    {
        var seconds:uint=time.getSeconds();
        var minutes:uint=time.getMinutes();
        var hours:uint=time.getHours();         

        this.secondHand.rotation = 180 + (seconds * 6);         
        this.minuteHand.rotation = 180 + (minutes * 6);
        this.hourHand.rotation = 180 + (hours * 30) + (minutes * 0.5);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the focal point is the upper left corner. So it will this point to rotate around the rotation. Must be to you as the middle position of the left middle point. To do this, create a parent container names `secondContainer` to add `secondHand`. after the `secondHand` point move to the center position to relative parent. Then change the rotation of the parent container.

Applied the concept of the above code below. Copy and paste.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.geom.Point;

const CLOCK_CENTER_POINT = new Point(stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2);

var secondContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(secondContainer);
secondContainer.x = CLOCK_CENTER_POINT.x;
secondContainer.y = CLOCK_CENTER_POINT.y;

var secondHand:Shape =new Shape();
const SECOND_LINE_WIDTH:Number = 2.0
const SECOND_LINE_HEIGHT:Number = 100;
secondHand.x = SECOND_LINE_WIDTH/2;
secondHand.y = -SECOND_LINE_HEIGHT;
secondHand.graphics.lineStyle(SECOND_LINE_WIDTH,0x000000,1.0);
secondHand.graphics.moveTo(0,SECOND_LINE_HEIGHT);
secondHand.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
secondContainer.addChild(secondHand);

var minContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(minContainer);
minContainer.x = CLOCK_CENTER_POINT.x;
minContainer.y = CLOCK_CENTER_POINT.y;

var minHand:Shape =new Shape();
const MIN_LINE_WIDTH:Number = 2.0
const MIN_LINE_HEIGHT:Number = 80;
minHand.x = MIN_LINE_WIDTH/2;
minHand.y = -MIN_LINE_HEIGHT;
minHand.graphics.lineStyle(MIN_LINE_WIDTH,0x00ff00,1.0);
minHand.graphics.moveTo(0,MIN_LINE_HEIGHT);
minHand.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
minContainer.addChild(minHand);

var hourContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(hourContainer);
hourContainer.x = CLOCK_CENTER_POINT.x;
hourContainer.y = CLOCK_CENTER_POINT.y;

var hourHand:Shape =new Shape();
const HOUR_LINE_WIDTH:Number = 2.0
const HOUR_LINE_HEIGHT:Number = 50;
hourHand.x = HOUR_LINE_WIDTH/2;
hourHand.y = -HOUR_LINE_HEIGHT;
hourHand.graphics.lineStyle(HOUR_LINE_WIDTH,0xff0000,1.0);
hourHand.graphics.moveTo(0,HOUR_LINE_HEIGHT);
hourHand.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
hourContainer.addChild(hourHand);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);

function onEnter(e:Event):void
{
    var time:Date = new Date();

    secondContainer.rotation = time.seconds*6+(time.milliseconds/(1000/6));
    minContainer.rotation = time.minutes*6+(time.seconds/10);
    hourContainer.rotation = time.hours*30+(time.minutes/2);
}
```